# Using Extension Methods in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have inherited a code base that I am trying to work with. I have a need to add some basic HTML attributes. Currently, in my .cshtml file, there is a block like this:

```
@Html.DropDown(model => model.SomeValue, Model.SomeList)
```

This references a function in `Extensions.cs`. This function looks like the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDown<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<string> items, string classes = "form-control")
{
  var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  attributes.Add("class", classes);

  return System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(html, expression, itemList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() }), null, attributes);
}
```

I now have a case where I need to disable the drop down in some scenarios. I need to evaluate the value of `Model.IsUnknown` (which is a bool) to determine whether or not the drop down list should be enabled or not.

My question is, how do I disable a drop down list if I need to? At this point, I do not know if I need to update my .cshtml or the extension method.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an optional parameter in your extension method for disabling named `enabled`and bydefaut it will be `true` and from view pass `bool` parameter to disable or enable it:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDown<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<string> items, string classes = "form-control",bool enabled=true)
{
  var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  attributes.Add("class", classes);
  if(!enabled)
     attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");

  return System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(html, expression, itemList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() }), null, attributes);
}
```

and now in View:

```
@Html.DropDown(model => model.SomeValue, Model.SomeList,enabled:false)
```