# TextBoxFor-extension not replacing underscores with hyphens

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-data-attribute

I have some kind of overload for the TextBoxFor-extension in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. The method looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FormGroupTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this MyHelper<TModel> myHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
```

The MyHelper has internally a HtmlHelper-property used for the "normal" MVC stuff which I don't have an overload for.

In the method I create

```
var routeValueDict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) {{"class", "form-control"}};
```

because I need to add some classes here.

Next call is:

```
var propertyInput = myHelper.HtmlInternal.TextBoxFor(expression, routeValueDict);
```

Which calls the default `TextBoxFor()` method.

When I call the extension like

```
@My.FormGroupTextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @data_blur_update = "title", @data_blur_target_id = string.Format("eventName{0}", eventId) })
```

it won't replace the `data_blur_update` with `data-blur-update` in the rendered HTML. Why?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not directly **data-**??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: As of data-?? will not compile: `Invalid anonymous type member declarator`

Comment: remove **@** it is not needed, it can be cause of that

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Same error. Event if I add `some_data = "SomeValue"`it still will not render `some-data`

Comment: Can you show your complete helper method?

Comment: ``RouteValuesDictionary`` may be culprit

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Can't show you more, sorry. But the code shown contains the main-parts. Regarding the `RouteValuesDictionary`. What would be an alternative here?

Comment: I am not on system currently but what I remember route value dictionary , and htmlAttributes dictionary are different things and of course different purpose

Comment: see this post, it may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610938/using-extension-methods-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
var routeValueDict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) {{"class", "form-control"}};
```

to

```
var routeValueDict = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
routeValueDict.Add("class", "form-control");
```

which then will contain the correct attributes with hyphens instead of the underscores.